# Point a normal vector towards a point in 3D-Space

Tags: 3d, mathematics, vector-graphics

Given a normal vector in 3D-Space, how can I rotate the vector, such it points to a point in 3D-Space.

I tried couple of ways doing this, which ended up looking completely wrong.

[image]

Comment: If the answer from @lightxbulb isn't what you are looking for then perhaps you could clarify your questions some.

Comment: Vectors do not have position, only direction and magnitude, so creating a vector that "points to a point in 3D-Space" isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e,f$ be the two edges of the triangle.  Let's construct an orthonormal system: $e = normalize(e)$, $n = normalize(e\times f)$, $f = n \times e$, where $\times$ is the cross product. Now compute:

$$e' = e - \frac{e \cdot n'}{1+(n\cdot n')}(n+n')$$

$$f' = f - \frac{f \cdot n'}{1+(n\cdot n')}(n+n')$$

Then the rotation matrix is:

$$R = \begin{bmatrix} e' & f' & n'\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e^T \\ f^T \\ n^T \end{bmatrix}.$$

Note that the computation of $e'$ and $f'$  breaks for $n' = -n$.